# Extract records from table on dynamic interval based on column value spilling over

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as below

| id | key | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 0 | newYork |
| 12 | 0 | Washington |
| 13 | 1 | Washington |
| 14 | 1 | newYork |
| 15 | 2 | Washington |
| 16 | 3 | Washington |
| 17 | 3 | Washington |
| 18 | 4 | Luxemberg |

wish to extract information based on key so that min records per page would be 3 and if key at record 3 is still there for next few records need to consider subsequent records so results sets would appear like

Page 1

| id | key | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 0 | newYork |
| 12 | 0 | Washington |
| 13 | 1 | Washington |
| 14 | 1 | newYork |

Page 2

| id | key | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 2 | Washington |
| 16 | 3 | Washington |
| 17 | 3 | Washington |

Page 3

| id | key | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18 | 4 | Luxemberg |

Comment: isn't that not a problem with the reporting tool you are using

Comment: No I need to query table and have min 3 rows returned and if 3 rd rows key is spilling to next row I need to keep on reading until it ends and consider that as page

Comment: "considering as a page" does sounds like a reporting function though; how would you expect the output *from a query* to look like - it won't be split into 'pages' as you've shown; I guess you could add a page number as another column, but that's not what you've shown. I also don't understand your logic to define each page - why does page 1 have 4 rows but page 2 only has 3, for example? - or what "spilling over" means here. Please edit your question to explain more clearly, possibly with more examples.

Comment: It looks like the first page has 4 because he wants to keep all of the same KEYs on the same page. So the first page has KEY 0, but there are only 2 and he is requiring a minimum of 3 rows. So the third row would be KEY1, but this would require all KEY1's to be on that page as well. Once he clears all of the KEY1, he moves to the next page with KEY2 and meets the 3 row minimum by adding the 2 rows for KEY3. Apparently the last page can have less than 3 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row processing:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY id
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS page
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( any_row{1,3} same_key* )
  DEFINE same_key AS PREV(key) = key
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, key, address) AS
SELECT 11, 0, 'newYork' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 0, 'Washington' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 1, 'Washington' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 1, 'newYork' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15, 2, 'Washington' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 16, 3, 'Washington' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 17, 3, 'Washington' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 18, 4, 'Luxemberg' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | PAGE | KEY | ADDRESS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 | 0 | newYork |
| 12 | 1 | 0 | Washington |
| 13 | 1 | 1 | Washington |
| 14 | 1 | 1 | newYork |
| 15 | 2 | 2 | Washington |
| 16 | 2 | 3 | Washington |
| 17 | 2 | 3 | Washington |
| 18 | 3 | 4 | Luxemberg |

If you only want a certain page then add a `WHERE` filter for that at the end of the query.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Pg2rpbIA)